# Compile Python Code to Pascal DLL

Tags: c++, python, dll, freepascal, shedskin

I have a program written in [Free Pascal](http://www.freepascal.org/). It imports functions from a DLL selected at runtime. They are imported with the `pascal;` keyword. I want to extend this program using python code. As I found out [shedskin](https://code.google.com/p/shedskin/) could be helpful for me in this situation. How do I need to proceed? In fact I want to "compile python code to a DLL". Additional to any free or open source tool/compiler I can use Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 and VC++ to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pascal` modifier is a statement of a [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions). Parameters are pushed onto the stack left to right. Compare to the `cdecl` calling convention where the parameters are pushed right to left to support [variadic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) functions in C. The `stdcall` modifier is another right to left calling convention.

Free Pascal supports both calling conventions. Here is [cdecl](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu65.html), [stdcall](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu79.html) and [pascal](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu73.html#x177-18700014.9.10) for Free Pascal. The calling conventions are definitely NOT compatible. If you call a function expected it arguments in a certain order with the stack arranged in the other order -- bad things will happen.

You will probably need to use cdecl to extend Free Pascal with Python that has been compiled into C++ code with shedskin. I think **all** Windows DLL's use the pascal conversion regardless of the language the DLL was written in however.

So make sure you use the right calling convention -- depending where you are using the code.

Comment: Afaik Pascal<>stdcall on Free Pascal. For windows dlls you want stdcall. http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu79.html#x183-19300014.9.16

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Pascal can use c foreign functions, using the python c-api directly is possible.  I think your first step though, is understanding the api python exposes for embedding cpython in other applications.

http://docs.python.org/2/extending/

Comment: Free Pascal also supports ActiveX IDispatch interfaces, like Delphi. This is sometimes more convenient to interface to scripting languages. Maybe it is wiser to have a look at various Delphi<->Python bridges.